# RecycleView findViewByPosition returns null after rotation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I have a list of items within the RecycleView, where I scroll until the middle of the list. Then I rotate the tablet, but the list shows the first item instead of the position before.

I did some debugging and the findViewByPosition(position) returns NULL under the hood (I am calling the smoothScrollToPosition).

Could someone please tell me why this method returns null? Had any of you have similar issues before?

(I am using an activity with two viewController, one for Portrait and one for Landscape. When the activity onSaveInstance get called I'm saving the position of the item to pass to recycleview.smoothScrollToPosition(pos) in onRestoreInstanceState()).

**UPDATE**
As it turned out the *findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition* works fine, when I rotating from Landscape to Portrait, but not verse. The only different that, on portrait my RecycleView is within a NestedScrollView. Furthermore the scrollTo doesn't work either. Let me know, if anyone have met with this issue already.

Comment: returns `"The child view that represents the given position or null if the position is not laid out"` you got `null` because `"the position is not laid out"`